# Stata - How to get Indicator Variable Indicators (Yes/No) to Appear in esttab LaTeX Output (when FE absorbed)

Tags: stata

I run -reghdfe-, a fixed effect model. Using -esttab, indicate()- I would like to append which FE are included, in an automated fashion.

See two examples:
[Stata - How to get Indicator Variable Indicators (Yes/No) to Appear in esttab LaTeX Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34297579/stata-how-to-get-indicator-variable-indicators-yes-no-to-appear-in-esttab-la/76207434#76207434)
and
[Stata tables: Using esttab, indicate() with xtreg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089701/stata-tables-using-esttab-indicate-with-xtreg)

Where the first example works if we use i.myFactorvariable. However, I run

```
reghdfe y x, cl(i.industry) a(i.industry)
```

Can I also here append cells in a way similar to: "Industry FE" "YES/NO" , using esttab?

Comment: An option was suggested using -estadd- 
https://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2012-05/msg01359.html
I am wondering if a shorter option is possible (as in the links within the original post).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, `esttab, indicate()` parses the column names of the parameter vector `e(b)` to search for the indicator variables. As reghdfe does not contain the fixed effects in there, the search is therefore unsuccessful.

As a quick fix, you can run:

```
reghdfe y x o.industry, absorb(industry) cluster(industry)
```

This adds industry as an omitted variable to the regression (this does not alter the result but creates an entry in `e(b)` as a missing value). The downside of this fix is that if you omit the fixed effects but keep the `o.industry`, the output will show erroneously a `"yes"`, even though the variable is **not** included in the regression. As a side note, you can omit the `i.` in the absorb and cluster option.

Example:

```
sysuse auto, clear

// initial problem
reghdfe price turn, absorb(foreign)
est store test1
// quick fix
reghdfe price turn o.foreign, absorb(foreign)
est store test2
// incorrect indication
reghdfe price turn o.foreign, noabsorb
est store test3

esttab test1 test2 test3, indicate(foreign)
```

Output:

```
. esttab test*, indicate(foreign)

------------------------------------------------------------
                      (1)             (2)             (3)   
                    price           price           price   
------------------------------------------------------------
turn                379.2***        379.2***        207.6** 
                   (4.12)          (4.12)          (2.76)   

_cons             -8871.0*        -8871.0*        -2065.0   
                  (-2.42)         (-2.42)         (-0.69)   

foreign                No             Yes             Yes   
------------------------------------------------------------
N                      74              74              74   
------------------------------------------------------------
t statistics in parentheses
* p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001
```

Comment: The simplest solution is here https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1734703-automatically-add-fixed-effect-indicators-to-esttab-after-reghdfe-using-indicate

Answer (score 0):

I think *outreg2* will help with appending cells similar to what you want

Comment: -outreg2- does a similar job, but for personal reasons of repeatedly appending results for each outcome variable, I prefer remaining in -esttab-

Comment: the solution is posted here https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1734703-automatically-add-fixed-effect-indicators-to-esttab-after-reghdfe-using-indicate